# Acceptance Testing - Check Email Received

Tags: testing, acceptance

I have some acceptance test allows a Windows service to send an email out via smtp, does anyone know of a good way to check if a email has been received via code, at present being sent to an Exchange Mail Box?

Regards

Iain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft offers an SDK for Exchange. The following specifies that (in 2010 at least - since you don't mention version) you can get an XML dump of emails: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd877045%28v=EXCHG.140%29.aspx